# Does adding ROW_NUMBER to query get sorted automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It seems if I add `ROW_NUMBER` in a simple `select` query, the results are sorted automatically by the `ROW_NUMBER` column even without `order by` added to the `select` query at the end. I tried this on

- without `ROW_NUMBER` - results are in random order
- with `ROW_NUMBER over (order by some_col)` - results automatically ordered by this `ROW_NUMBER` column
- with `ROW_NUMBER over (order by some_col desc)` - results again automatically order by this `ROW_NUMBER` column reflecting the new direction

Why is it behaving like this? Is there an implicit `order by` when using `ROW_NUMBER`?

If this is vendor specific, I was testing on MSSQL2014

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, the order that records are returned is at the mercy of the query planner. It makes sense that the query plan for a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X)` would have an internal _order by x_ operator, and if there happened to be no other order operator after that, it would naturally appear in that order

Comment: @user1589188 . . . Run both `row_numbers()` at the same time.  See?  SQL does not guarantee the ordering of results *unless the outer query has an `ORDER BY`*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ORDER BY Clause in the window function only controls the order of the rows considered for the window function. It does not guarantee the final result set order.

[Over clause](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-the-over-clause)

> **Note**: The ORDER BY clause in the OVER clause only controls the order that the rows in the partition will be utilized by the window
> function. It does not control the order of the final result set.
> Without an ORDER BY clause on the query itself, the order of the rows
> is not guaranteed. You may notice that your query may be returning in
> the order of the last specified OVER clause – this is due to the way
> that this is currently implemented in SQL Server. If the SQL Server
> team at Microsoft changes the way that it works, it may no longer
> order your results in the manner that you are currently observing. If
> you need a specific order for the result set, you must provide an
> ORDER BY clause against the query itself.

Comment: @user1589188, no in MSSQL also, it is not guaranteed. You need to have ORDER BY clause outside to guarantee the ORDER of resultset